# How to extract frames from video, process it, and combine it into video file in android

Tags: android, video

How to extract frames from video, process it, and combine it into video file.
Jcodec - very slow. 
JavaCV - unsuitable, because it under GNU GPL.
OpenCV - because it uses OpenCV manager.
PS video from SD card, not camera.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language. I personally use OpenCV though.

Comment: ok, I delete tag. But openCV doesn't support videocapturing from filesystem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question for StackOverflow, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

I asked a similar question here: [Recording Live OpenCV Processing on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663864/recording-live-opencv-processing-on-android)

That's specific for OpenCV, but the end result was using JavaCV and FFmpeg to create video files. That's agnostic of the input.

[Here](https://github.com/vanevery/JavaCV_0.3_stream_test) is the FFmpeg part. You'd just need to swap out the camera for extracting the frames from wherever you're getting them. FFmpeg can probably do that as well.