# Android OpenCV blur artifacts

Tags: android, opencv

I've come across an interesting artifact while blurring images in an Android application with OpenCV 3.0.0 on a Nexus 9 tablet.

This is the input image:
[image: input image]

And this is what I get after blurring the image with OpenCV `blur()`. Notice, there are color curves on the white/gray wall.
[image: blurred image with artifacts]

My code is based on the OpenCV Camera Preview tutorial.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();

    Imgproc.blur(mRgba, mRgba, new org.opencv.core.Size(20,20));

    return mRgba;
}
```

I get the same effect when blurring inside C++ library called by the application.

The strange thing is that if I save the blurred image as a `png` like this:

```
Mat bgr = new Mat(mRgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, bgr, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);

Imgcodecs.imwrite("blurred.png", bgr);
```

then the artifacts are not there. Also on a different phone (HTC HD2) there are no artifacts.

I've set the frame size to 640x480, so the blurred image (as returned by `onCameraFrame`) must be resized by a factor of 3 in the function `deliverAndDrawFrame` in class `CameraBridgeViewBase` when being drawn onto the canvas. But when I save a video of the blurred input using `MediaRecorder` from the surface ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663864/recording-live-opencv-processing-on-android/33074249#33074249), thus the bitmap that is drawn onto screen and into the video is the same), there are again no artifacts.

So I'm at a loss, what is the source of the color curves and how to get rid of them. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you have any luck figuring it out?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I've not found the culprit.

Comment: Hey guys, did you figure out any solution for this?

Comment: No, I've not found any solution.